# Adding error message to an input field with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble displaying an error message in my form using JavaScript.

Here is part of my form and the input field that I'm trying to access with JS. I'd like to add the error message underneath inside the span tags.

```
<form name="subform" id="subform" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return checkForBlank()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="text" id="subcim" name="subcim" class="form-control">
        <label for="subcim" class="">Title</label>
    </div>
    <span class="error_form" id="subcim_error_message"></span>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function checkForBlank() {
if(document.geElementById("subcim").value == "") {
    document.getElementById("subcim_error_message").textContent="You must add a title!";
    return false;
}
}
```

So basically the error message should appear when the input field is left empty. But it's not shown.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try `innerHtml` instead of textContent?

Comment: What are the settings of your `error_form` CSS class? If that is used to hide the element, you're not doing anything to change that.

Comment: Looks like a typo, `document.geElementById("subcim")` should be `document.getElementById("subcim")`.

Comment: error_form is only used to add text color.

Comment: @Jesse Kernaghan: gosh, thanks man :) I've been rewriting this part so many times, didn't even notice. It works now. Thanks

Comment: Check your console.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @torazaburo, browser support. nothing else.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad `textContent` is not only supported in all browsers, it is the preferred best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementById("subcim_error_message").innerHTML="You must add a title!";

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it didn't work. When I try to submit the form with the empty input field, it shows me this message: "Please fill in the required fields." only, no form is shown. I'm guessing it's a default browser message.

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. A "t" was left from "getElementById"

Comment: When you post an answer, you should test it. Make sure you can reproduce the OP's problem; then make sure your fix fixes it. Then post your fixed code, along with an explanation of why it fixes it.